# How to drop a column(and index) in Postgres concurrently?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I need to drop a column from my (large) Postgres table. This is simple enough, but there is also an index on the column.
I can see that the index is implicitly dropped when I remove the column with `ALTER TABLE`, but I understand I should use `CONCURRENTLY` when dropping an index.

So my question is:
Is it appropriate to perform this operation as two queries. i.e.:

```
DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF EXISTS myTable_myColumn_idx;
ALTER TABLE myTable DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS myColumn;
```

Or could that result in a race condition, where the alter table is executed while the index is still being dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping an index is normally a very fast operation. I would test it first with a big index and see if it is really worth the effort to drop the index separately.

If you find that it indeed takes a long time for you, use the statements you propose, but don't try to run them in parallel (they will lock each other), but in a single database session. That will keep the time when the table is locked to a minimum.